# Spring XD: separate configuration for multiple module instances

Tags: spring, spring-xd

My Spring XD stream definitions contain references to the same custom module but with different configuration parameters, e.g.

```
stream create --name mystream1 --definition "tcp --port=4444 | mycustommod --myprop='very long property value 1'" | log"
stream create --name mystream2 --definition "tcp --port=5555 | mycustommod --myprop='very long property value 2'" | log"
```

I can put long module configuration into an external module configuration file. But that works only for the first module instance. For the rest of the module instances that I'm using in my stream definitions I have to override the externalized config in the stream definition directly.

That bloats the stream definitions if I have many [or long] property values to override.

Is there a way to put different module *instance* configurations to the external config files just in order to keep the stream definitions clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a property placeholder in the module config eg

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${xd.module.config.location}\processor\${xd.module.name}\${xd.stream.name}.properties"
     ignore-resource-not-found="true" local-override="true"/>
```

Then in your case you put your properties in

```
<module_config_location>\processor\mycustommod\mystream1.properties
<module_config_location>\processor\mycustommod\mystream2.properties
```

etc

Comment: That's a neat approach, thanks!
It looks like I can also use ${xd.module.index} in case if I have several module instances within the same stream definition.

Comment: Important side-effect to note here: the property file is present overrides (takes precedence) the options explicitly provided in the stream definition.